# NGINX : Unable to whitelist list of IPs on phpmyadmin route

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a website running in production and I need to disable the route phpmyadmin and allow a list of IPs only.

> **Issue**: The following is **denying all the IPs** including the ones which are allowed.

file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
 location /phpmyadmin {
                allow X.X.X.X;
                allow Y.Y.Y.Y;
                allow Z.Z.Z.Z;
                deny all;

                root /usr/share/;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                }

                location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                        root /usr/share/;
                }
        }
```

I need to fix this to allow 3-4 IPs only on this route. Please help. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tested successfully without the deny statement?  Have you checked the logs for the denied requests?